# Problems with jar with external libraries

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

I created a jar for my program but I can't start it.

I created it with IntelliJ and it works when I launch it from IntelliJ, but when I try to start from the jar it doesn't work.
I made my project with maven and I had to import two external libraries: Selenium and Apache Poi, I tried to comment the line with that dependencies and it works, but I need to use them.

The error the Windows PowerShell gave me is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.calcoloeffemeridi.Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.calcoloeffemeridi.Launcher
```

I read a lot of possible solutions on web but any can help me.

Comment: Take a look in your jar manifest to see if the main-class: is referenced correctly. The META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  the Launcher main class should be in the jar file , but in all whatever the main class , it should be specified in MANIFEST.MF   this start a classfile "using" aka external jar library on windows java -cp "nicephotog-web-tools.jar";. TestSqlTime to execute a jar using this library but executing a different jar... something like  'java -cp "nicephotog-web-tools.jar";. -jar somejarfile'    and somejarfile would have a main class in it specified in MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Now i changed the library Selenium and i use Jsoup. I tried to change also the JDK on my pc and the error now is "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application". What does it means?

Comment: Some JDK's do not ship with JavaFX , JavaFX is a much commercial (payed license) piece of Java , it is ony available in some older JDK versions free.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a jar with the libraries inside or include those in the class path.
in order to have those inside the jar you can use the shade plugin.
Add this to the pom

```
  <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.4.1</version>
<configuration>
    <transformers>
        <transformer
            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>app.Main</mainClass> <!-- Here you should put the main class of your application -->
        </transformer>
    </transformers>
    <filters>
        <filter> <!-- This filter is needed to avoid a bug in the shade plugin -->
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </filter>
    </filters>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions></plugin>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, now the problem looks like JavaFX runtime components are missing, do you know the possible solution?